# different behaviour of scanf function with different format-specifiers

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

when i use scanf with %d or %f, it skips white-space characters. on the other hand when used with %c it reads the white-space characters.can someone elaborate on this as to why this  happens?

with %d or %f like the code below it skips white-space characters automatically

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
int i;
scanf("%d ",&i);
}
```

if i read the input like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
char ch;
scanf(" %c ",&ch);
scanf(" %c",&ch);  /*or like this*/
}
```

it skips white-space characters.
why is scanf showing different behaviours with format-specifiers????

Comment: I don't suppose [this would help](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). The description of format specifiers and their modifiers is pretty detailed.

Comment: "why this happens?" - Because `%c` looks for *any* character.

Comment: Yes, how would '%c' find a whitespace character if it always skipped them? None of your input would ever have spaces in it.

Comment: Note that you can skip over leading whitespace by using a blank space in the format string, such as `" %c"`; this way you'll pick up the first non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it's because a white space character is not valid for `%d` or `%f`, so they will skip them.

But a white space character is a valid character, so `%c` will try to process it.

> **C99 §7.19.6.2 *The fscanf function* section 8**
>
> Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless
>   the specification includes a `[`,`c`,or `n` specifier.